# Ajax post to JSP doesn't redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a basic ajax post when the form is submitted but no redirection to the jsp happens on succession. If I programatically set the redirect it seems to create a new jsp instead of working with the jsp page that has POST data. I've discovered that by debugging and looking at the network.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Test.jsp",
        data: {"array": json},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(response){                                             
        }
} );
```

I browsed stack overflow is some were suggesting to do this `window.location.replace(response.redirect)` but the response I get back is an html doc.  So response.redirect is undefined.

May I ask how do I post and redirect to the jsp that has the data

Answer (score 0):

You may just want to submit the form to the page you are posting/redirecting to.

```
<form action = "page.jsp" method = "POST">
     Name: <input type = "text" name = "name">
     <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
</form>
```

There's typically no need for ajax when redirecting.

Comment: Well the post i made is a simplified and generic post so it can possibly be recreated. My ajax call is within a javascript function that is triggered by a form's action.  Here's the full example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44555096/how-to-create-and-post-a-form-properly